# How to return multiple json objects as HttpResponseMessage through Web API?

Tags: c#, json, api, asp.net-web-api

I'm having a problem getting multiple Json objects using `HttpResponseMessage`. How can this be acheived without wrapping the string as Json?

This is the code that I have tried so far...

```
private HttpResponseMessage SetToJson(string jsonString)        
{     
  string str = "ABC";

  HttpRequestMessage Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
  Request.Properties.Add(HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey, new HttpConfiguration());
  Request.Content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

  return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { jsonString, str }, JsonMediaTypeFormatter.DefaultMediaType);
}
```

It works fine, but it appends **\r\n"** by itself. How can this be fixed? Is there any other alternative?

This is the returned response by the above code

```
{"jsonString":["{\r\n  \"resourceType\": \"Patient\",\r\n  \"entry\": []\r\n}","ABC"]}
```

Comment: have you tried with Newtonsoft   JsonConvert.SerializeObject(YOUROBJECT, Formatting.None);

Comment: yes .. it produces same result

Comment: is it ok so?...

Comment: no... i still have same problem

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?  As it stands, the json text that you are returning is not really correctly formatted, ignoring the \r\n.  WebApi is attempting to serialize the json string that you have in an array with your str variable.  Are you trying to add a property to the json string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems as though you a serializing an object twice.

If the intention was to return proper objects then you need to deserialize the incoming `jsonString` back to an object before creating your anonymous object result which eventually get serialized back to json again in the http meddage response

```
private HttpResponseMessage SetToJson(string jsonString) { 
    string str = "ABC";

    var Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    Request.Properties.Add(HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey, new HttpConfiguration());
    Request.Content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { obj, str }, JsonMediaTypeFormatter.DefaultMediaType);
}
```